# How can I increment & add to array on mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my database, I have a `user` table with 2 columns: `score` & `history` :

[image]

I have another table called `card` containing some specific information & a card `_id`.

Each time a specific card is clicked, I would like the `'/CardClicked'` router to be called for :

- Additional (**increment**) a specific number value (1.5) on `score` column
- **Add** the cart `_id` value on the array of `history` column: (to save, which card the user clicked)

I wanted to have something like that in my database:

```
users:
{ "_id" : 1, "score" :  6.0, "history" : [ 62k6hf45b0af050fe, 69k5hf45b0af450fg, 65k5hf45b0af450fg, ]}
{ "_id" : 2, "score" :  4.5, "history" : [ 65k5hf45b0af450fg,] }
{ "_id" : 3, "score" : 10.0, "history" : [ 66k5hf45t0af930rp, 67k5hf45b0af450fg, 62k6hf45b0af050fe, 61y5hf884b0af450vb, ] }
```

But, idk why it doesn't update properly on columns, however i don't have any error, that my code i made it :

My UserSchema.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
score: {
  type: Number,
},
history: {
  type: [String]
 },
 createdAt: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now,
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

My router.js :

```
app.post('/CardClicked', async function (req, res){

  console.log("User ID "+req.user._id, "Card ID : "+req.body._id);

try{       
   const condition = { _id: req.user._id };

   //the req.body._id contain the card id from my front to send that to router
   const putPostID = { $addToSet: { history: req.body._id }};

   const additionalPoints = {$inc : { score : 1.5 }};


   await User.findOneAndUpdate(condition, additionalPoints, putPostID, {upsert: true})


}catch(err){
 res.status(500).send({error: err })
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every update operation must go into one object. In your case:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(condition, {
    $inc: { score: 1.5 },
    $addToSet: { history: req.body._id },
  }, 
  { upsert: true },
)
```

Comment: thank you, it worked ! , on the other hand, I don't know if you were wrong for the ```history``` which is duplicated ‍♂️ ?